# Is there any way to print out debug statements in Postgres PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm thinking something in the lines of [`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67307), it allows you to trace what's going on in a stored procedure in the exactly same way you would use `printf`, `puts` or some other `STDIO` writing proc in a "normal" programming language, i.e.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I got here:'||:new.col||' is the new value');
```

is there any way of doing this in Postgres?

If not, what's the "community way" of doing this? Creating a table with a string row and inserting debug values there?

Comment: @McNets The question is more broad here, but the answer is the same

Answer (score 23):

You can use `RAISE NOTICE` like this:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'I got here:% is the new value', NEW.col;
```

A notice won't terminate execution, it is a kind of message that is sent to the client asynchronously.

Comment: Thaaank you, bravo, note to self, the colons are single :D

Comment: And for n00bs like me: No, `raise notice` does not stop execution.  And that is some kind of formal string.